# How to parse line by line WinHTTP response: UTF-8 encoded CSV?

Tags: vba, csv, utf-8, httpresponse, winhttp

As the next step for my happily solved problem ([Not understanding why WinHTTP does NOT authenticate certain HTTPS resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184926/not-understanding-why-winhttp-does-not-authenticate-certain-https-resource)) I need to prettily parse obtained CSV. At the moment I use the following solution:

```
If HTTPReq.Status = 200 Then
    If FSO.FileExists(CSV_Path) = True Then FSO.DeleteFile (CSV_Path)
    Set FileStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    FileStream.Open
    FileStream.Type = 1
    FileStream.Write HTTPReq.responseBody
    FileStream.SaveToFile (CSV_Path)
    FileStream.Close
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Redmine Timelog").Refresh
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable_RM").PivotCache.Refresh
End If
```

That is, I save CSV to disk and then link it as data source to Excel. However, I'd like to have my Excel book self-sufficient, with no need to create additional files (for some quite obvious reasons).

The solution is pretty simple in my case: store `WinHTTP.responseText` line by line on the separate Excel sheet (instead of currently stored linked CSV) and then use `Text to Data` Excel conversion. However, I face the following immediate troubles:

1. CSV is UTF-8 encoded, while raw WinHTTP response text seems to be NOT. Is there any way to interpret it using desired encoding?
2. How to split CSV into lines? Use `Split` function or whatever else? CSV seems to use some of standard NewLine chars, and the data 99% should have NOT any of these.

There are many similar troubles solved, but I found nothing clear and acceptable for VBA so far, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `ResponseText` is interpreted in the encoding the server declares in the HTTP Content-Type header

Comment: @Esailija Below is the valuable part of `HTTPReq.getAllResponseHeaders`: `Content-Length: 101967
Content-Type: text/csv; header=present
Status: 200
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
X-Runtime: 2163
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="timelog.csv"` I'm not sure for the CSV in my case encoding is expected.

Comment: Since there is no `charset` specified in the `Content-Type` header, the default charset is `ISO-8859-1` per [RFC 2616 Section 3.7.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.7.1): "When no explicit charset parameter is provided by the sender, media subtypes of the "text" type are defined to have a default charset value of "ISO-8859-1" when received via HTTP". Unless WinHTTP is choosing to analyze the data itself, such as by lookin for a UTF-8 BOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found both solutions on my own:

1. CSV to UTF-8 conversion with the help of ADODB.Stream (see for more: http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_binarytostring/)
2. Splitting CSV and further parsing of strings array using `Text to Data` Excel routine

Below is the related part of code:

```
'CSV to UTF-8
Set FileStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
FileStream.Open
FileStream.Type = 1 'Binary
FileStream.Write HTTPReq.responseBody
FileStream.Position = 0
FileStream.Type = 2 'Text
FileStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
CSV_Text = FileStream.ReadText
FileStream.Close
'CSV Splitting
CSV_Strings = Split(Trim(CSV_Text), vbLf)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RM_Log").Cells.ClearContents
Set OutputRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RM_Log").Range("A1:A" & UBound(CSV_Strings) + 1)
OutputRange = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(CSV_Strings)
OutputRange.TextToColumns Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RM_Log").Range("A1"), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
    Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 3), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
    Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1)), DecimalSeparator:=".", _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

As a result, my Excel file is now totally self-sufficient. Hope this will help someone else as well. Many thanks to everyone who left comments - they narrowed my search.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
OutputRange = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(CSV_Strings)
```

should be like this

```
OutputRange.Formula = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(CSV_Strings)
```

Comment: what's the difference - the original code works pretty nice?