# Excel Macro To import CSV data fails with TextFileParseType

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to load CSV data from URL to my MS Excel sheet with this code:

```
Sub LoadCSVData()
    Dim sSheetName As String
    sSheetName = "Sheet1"

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sSheetName).UsedRange.ClearContents

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sSheetName).QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://sampledomain.com/mydata.csv" _
        , Destination:=Sheets(sSheetName).Range("$A$1"))
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

It throws the

> error: 1004 Application-defined or object defined error

on the lines with `TextFileParseType` and `TextFileCommaDelimiter`.
When i comment them out, the macro works, but all is loaded into `A1` cell and it is not parsed.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nearly duplicate of [Excel QueryTables.Add from URL Comma Delimited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470158/excel-querytables-add-from-url-comma-delimited)

Change "URL" to "TEXT" 
Here's my quick rework of your code:

```
Sub LoadCSVData()
    Dim sSheetName As String
    sSheetName = "Sheet1"
    Dim myTable As QueryTable
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sSheetName).UsedRange.ClearContents

Set myTable = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sSheetName).QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv" _
        , Destination:=Sheets(sSheetName).Range("$A$1"))

    With myTable
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```