# import comma separated numbers to excel from web

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, excel

I am trying to import comma separated numbers in a cell in excel. It looks like this on web:

```
000002678,000002737,000002827,000004326,000008528
```

But as soon as I import it in excel it transforms to following:

```
2,678,000,002,737,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
```

How can I maintain the format like it is on web and not treat it as one big number?

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://localhost:65076/TestData", Destination:=Range( _
    "$A$1"))
    .Name = "Test"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: What do you mean by "import ... in [E]xcel?"  What do you mean by "on [the] [W]eb?"  Are you manually copying and pasting text from a Web page into a cell?  Are you automatically scraping Web page contents or accessing a RESTful API?  Are you using the Excel automation API?  If so, which function and with what parameters?

Comment: @Jollymorphic There is an import From web option in Excel "Data->Get External Data->From Web" Where you can specify a url and import data from a particular website.

Comment: what version of excel do you use? i tested it in excel 2010 and worked. Selected the cell A1 and the Import from web then i put this url and checked the first div with numbers. Now i have those numbers comma seperated in A1 cell.

Comment: You need to set data separator as `comma` and set Data format as `text` to keep all leading zeros.

Comment: @PeterL. How to set data separator as comma?

Comment: Use `Text to Columns` feature: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14285131/1953175 - once I faced the same problem. First import your data as text, then use macro recorder to get the code while doing that manually.

Comment: @PeterL. When you say import your data as Text, do you mean have excel cell formatted as Text? I import my data from a website.

Comment: Yes, destination cells should be formatted as text.

Comment: @PeterL. Formatting Cell to Text and then importing from web displays: 2.678000002737E+39;
Original Content from web: 000002678,000002737,000002827,000004326,000008528

Comment: @PeterL. I Use QueryTables.add to import data from a website in excel

Answer (score 0):

@PeterL or user793468 Did you ever solve this? Because i have the exact same problem and the only solution i found was a workaround (that actually can work!)

Set Windows Region and Language settings: "Decimal Settings" from , to . and excel will not treat my case 016448,016501,017612,01... etc as one long number.

If you plan on running the script "autonomasly" then just have those settings in a virtual machine where you run the script.

Comment: I believe Changing the cell format to Text fixed the issue