# Invalid data format from request response - VBA

Tags: json, vba, excel

Trying to pull data from private page,  I am receiving a JSON response and would like to check whether everything is okay. The status of the request is fine (200), but if I use

```
Debug.Print (xmlhttp.responseText)
```

I see unknown ( for me ) format, it looks like:

> ?      ?s???+]?f? ?n??????w????@??E????LJ??n???

Do you know how to convert it to standard JSON code ?

If I use the same headers in Javascript, then everything is okay, so I would like to know why excel converting the response to such strange form

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the encoding. `Debug.Print` and the VBE want to work with ANSI/ASCII.

Comment: so where can I change it? sorry, I am begginer :-)

Comment: Look into how to use `StrConv`, see if it helps.

Comment: It looks like `responseText` failed to decode the response from `utf-8` to `utf-16`. It might be due to a header in the response. You'll probably have to convert the response with `ADODB.Stream` or `MultiByteToWideChar`. There's too many "?" to be due to the ANSI limitation of the immediate window.

Comment: Hey Florent, I don't understand what you mean. How to use ADOBD.Stream ?

Comment: @Vba_Beg, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252762/how-to-parse-line-by-line-winhttp-response-utf-8-encoded-csv

Comment: Thanks , but I see the following error: Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range or are in conflict with one another

Comment: the part of code: FileStream.Type = 1 'Binary
    FileStream.Write xmlhttp.responseText

Comment: may it be related to this :  FileStream.Type ?

Comment: should I change the type ?

Comment: @Vba_Beg, you need to keep the line `FileStream.Write HTTPReq.responseBody`. For the line  `FileStream.Charset`, you need to set the one returned by the response. It should be `utf-8`. Check the returned header `content-type`  with `xmlhttp.GetResponseHeader("content-type")`.

Comment: it returns application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: Changed the code to https://paste.ofcode.org/ahkgPQmWNcmqvvhPYpNbnP

Comment: But still see the safe text format :-

Comment: nothing change :-(

Comment: @Vba_Beg try `Cells(1, 1).Value = xmlhttp.responseTex` or `MsgBox xmlhttp.responseTex` instead of `Debug.Print (xmlhttp.responseText)` to output response. Then just copy the string and paste here.